# How to extract an array from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a .txt file with thousands of tensors written inside. My problem is that they are all written in the following format (it is a string):

```
' tensor([ 9.8228e-01, -2.6578e-01,  9.6711e-01,........, -0.3274, -0.3205])'
```

How can I convert this into an array of floats? I have problems with handling the 'e-01' parts as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What should be done with the `........` ?

Comment: sorry, the dots mean that there are many more numbers in between

Comment: That's a very inefficient and inprecise way to save numerical data. Do you by any chance have control over how the file is written in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just `map()` to `float` the strings obtained by splitting for `,` the substring between `[` and `]`:

```
s = 'tensor([ 9.8228e-01, -2.6578e-01,  9.6711e-01, -0.3274, -0.3205])'

list(map(float, s[s.find('[') + 1:s.find(']')].split(',')))
# [0.98228, -0.26578, 0.96711, -0.3274, -0.3205]
```

or to get to a NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np


np.fromiter(map(float, s[s.find('[') + 1:s.find(']')].split(',')), dtype=float)
# array([ 0.98228, -0.26578,  0.96711, -0.3274 , -0.3205 ])
```

---

## EDIT

NumPy offers a faster alternative using [`np.fromstring()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy.fromstring):

```
np.fromstring(s[s.find('['):], dtype=float, sep=', ')
```

which is substantially an optimized version of the above. Note that you would still need to remove the `tensor` part of the string.